# Get not overflowing text length dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, text

Is there a way to get the length of visible part of an overflown text (or the size of the overflown part, to calculate the rest, for the case) with CSS or JavaScript?

And if so, could it be calculated dynamically (i.e. on window resize?)

The idea is to make a read more button which span button always sticks at the end of the last visible line, it doesn't matter the screen size.

Comment: Instead, you can create a div for content and a read more button at the bottom. So you let CSS do its thing

Comment: What exactly do you need? There may be just part of a character showing so I’m not understanding the concept of length here.

Comment: The client is asking us a two line clamped text that shows three dots and Read More-Read Less button in React. He wants the button to show at the end of the second line, it doesn´t matter what size the screen is in. And while I´m able to just slice the text for different breakpoints, it doesn´t addapt well to the end-of-line all-breakpoints request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this involves a lot of factors, for instance, your "text" could be a mixture of text and other elements (`<b>`, `<i>`, `<img>`). Assuming it's just straight text, the following works by splitting the string at various halves, with successively smaller halves, to eventually arrive at the text that gives the same height as your source element with hidden overflow.

```
function getVisibleText(source)
{
    let yardstick = document.createElement(source.nodeName);
    let sourceRectangle = source.getBoundingClientRect();
    let text = source.textContent;
    
    yardstick.style.width = sourceRectangle.width + "px";
    yardstick.style.position = "absolute";
    yardstick.style.top = "-999px";
    yardstick.style.left = "-999px";
    yardstick.textContent = text;
    source.parentNode.appendChild(yardstick);
    
    let size = text.length;
    let difference = size;
    let yardstickRectangle = yardstick.getBoundingClientRect();
    let result = text;
    while((difference > 1 || yardstickRectangle.height > sourceRectangle.height) && size > 0)
    {
        difference = Math.round(difference / 2);
        if(yardstickRectangle.height > sourceRectangle.height)
            size -= difference;
        else
            size += difference;
        result = text.substring(0, size);
        yardstick.textContent = result;
        yardstickRectangle = yardstick.getBoundingClientRect();
    }
    yardstick.parentNode.removeChild(yardstick);
    
    // Trim to the last whole word
    let match = (new RegExp("\\s+\\S*?$", "g")).exec(result)[0];
    if(match)
        result = result.substring(0, result.length - match.length);

    return(result);
}
```